# Use same useState in different components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a main app and two components. It looks something like this:

`MainApp:`

```
const MainApp = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Component1 />
            <Component2 />
        </>
    );
};
```

`Component1:`

```
const Component1 = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setState(state => !state)}>Toggle</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

`Component2:`

```
type Props = {
    state?: boolean;
};

const Component2 = ({ state }: Props) => {
    
    return (
        <>
            {state ? <p>Hello</p> : <p>Not hello</p>}
        </>
    );
};
```

Right now it obviously doesn't work since `Component2` doesn't get the `state` from anywhere.

My problem is, how do I share the state between the two components, with the `MainApp` being the intermediary ? Do I create the `useState` variable in the `MainApp` instead of `Component1`, and then pass the `state` and `setState` to the toggle component `(Component1)`, and pass the state to `Component2`, or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: create the state variable in MainApp and pass it child components. that's better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `contextApi` to handle this. I have shared a sample code which helps you understand more about context api.

> Context api helps you share the states and functions of a component
> with other components inside the particular project.

In `Filecontext.jsx` you can see `createContext` which helps you in creating a context.

In `App.jsx`, we have created the states and functions which has to be shared among the components and wrapped the components which can access the datas with that context by importing it.

In `Formcomponent.jsx`, I am using `useContext` to use the states and functions created in the `App.jsx`.

Filecontext.jsx

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
export const Filecontext = createContext({});
```

App.jsx

```
import { Filecontext } from './Contexts/Filecontext';
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [mobileno, setMobileno] = useState("")
  const showAlert = () => {
    alert(`Hello ${name}`);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Filecontext.Provider value={{ name, setName, email, setEmail, mobileno, setMobileno, showAlert }}>
        <Formcomponent />
        <Listcomponent />
      </Filecontext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Formcomponent.jsx

```
import { Filecontext } from '../Contexts/Filecontext';
import { useContext } from 'react'

export default function Formcomponent() {
    const { setName, setEmail, setMobileno, showAlert } = useContext(Filecontext)

    return (
        <>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value) }} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Email : </label>
                <input type="email" onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Mobile No : </label>
                <input type="number" onChange={(e) => { setMobileno(e.target.value) }} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick={() => { showAlert() }} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useContext hook to share same data in your components.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext
or tools like redux.

Your question is a good question but it doesn't get solved with one line of code.

I mean above sources are for general state management.
If you have a really small app and you don't need to update state from different components etc. then you can just provide the data from parent of component 1 and 2

```
const MainApp = () => {
const [stateData,setStateData] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            <Component1 data={stateData}/>
            <Component2 data={stateData} />
        </>
    );
};
```

then access to that data in your components with props

```
const Component1 = (props) => {
   const dataFromParent = props.data
   const [stateData,setStateData] = useState(dataFromParent);
    return (
        <>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setState(state => !state)}>Toggle</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `useContext()` or redux you would need to create the state in the `MainApp` and then pass it to `Component1` and `Component2`.

```
// MainApp

const MainApp = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
            <Component1 setState={setState} />
            <Component2 state={state} />
        </>
    );
};
```

```
// Component1

type Component1Props = {
  setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>;
}

const Component1 = ({ setState } : Component1Props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setState((prev) => !prev)}>Toggle</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

```
// Component2

type Component2Props = {
    state?: boolean;
};

const Component2 = ({ state }: Component2Props) => {
    return (
        <>
            {state ? <p>Hello</p> : <p>Not hello</p>}
        </>
    );
};
```